# Can I Use C++ vector insted of queue for FIFO order

Tags: c++

Hi all Can I use vector instead of queue ?. I just want to push and pop to and from memory using different thread . And also I need to delete data after pop. Is there any advantage using vector over queue ?

Thanks in advance....

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A vector is analogous to a stack not to a queue. You may only push and pop from one side not push from one and pop from the other. A vector will give you the capability to access arbitrary element by its index in constant time but will not be able to efficiently remove elements from its beginning.

Comment: Theoretically you can, but you have to shift the elements yourself, to cover the gaps

Comment: I said `will not be able to efficiently...` you can but not efficiently

Comment: @Haris not in an efficient manner. That is the pop operation will be **very** slow

Comment: Hi thanks for the information. So it's better to use queue in my case.

Comment: @Haris yes definitely. A queue is meant to be used for FIFO container.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23375/discussion-between-haris-and-ivaylo-strandjev)

Answer (score 12):

It isn't wise, because a queue is FIFO, so you need to pop from the opposite end that you push into. For this, the structure to use is [`std::deque`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/deque), which is the structure that [`std::queue`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/queue) uses under the hood by default.

Answer (score 5):

You "can" use a vector over a queue, if the queue lifetime is short or if you know the maximum size of your queue. Just use a vector, push_back in it, and keep an index of where your "head" is.
For exemple if i push back 3 elements, and i want to pop one, i'll just increment my "head" index by one.

This technique as been explained by Chandler Carruth in this video:
https://youtu.be/fHNmRkzxHWs?t=2541

Answer (score 4):

Using vector for queue will force you to insert or delete elements from the first position of vector. The vector is contained as a single block of memory and such operation is costly. Queue may be implemented more efficiently.

Answer (score 1):

If you really need a vector for a FIFO, you may use `insert()` and `pop_back()`.

```
std::vector<glm::vec3> m_vertices;
glm::vec3 point1 = glm::vec3();
glm::vec3 point2 = glm::vec3();

m_vertices.insert(m_vertices.begin(), point1) ;

m_vertices.pop_back();
m_vertices.insert(m_vertices.begin(), point2);
```

Answer (score 1):

I have a similar use case, a difference being that I only need to populate the 'queue' once, then I need to consume *all* the elements *in the same order they were added*, after which I discard the queue.

Anyone having a similar case can simply

- use a vector
- fill it with a series of push_back() calls
- then use the entries in normal order (from *begin()* to *end()*)
- then just *clear()* the vector

I've not tested it yet, but will try it soon.